# ConnectionError between Python and ASP .Net core

Tags: python, c#, .net, asp.net-core, python-requests

I want to use the Python lib [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to connect to my ASP Net Core API point.

After trying to send a Json from Python to ASP Net core I get the following message:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/Search (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f66d3773880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

btw: I have only tried once to establish the connection ;-)

```
import requests
import json

class SearchApi:

@staticmethod
 def findFile(request):
    
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    url     = "http://localhost:5000/api/Search"
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(request.__dict__), headers=headers)

    return response.json()
```

and request class:

```
class Request:

def __init__(self, driveId, itemId, searchName):
    self.driveId = driveId
    self.itemId = itemId
    self.searchName = searchName
```

and Asp .Net Core back-End method:

```
        [ApiController]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
      public class SearchController : ControllerBase
         [HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> SearchFile([FromBody] SearchInfos searchInfos)
       {
        //......
        Console.WriteLine("Ping ! ! ");
        return Ok();
    }
```

With the backend, unfortunately, no request arrives from Python, but the Postman or Swagger tests are successful.

What mistake have I made in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

*The reason for the problem is that the ngrok proxy is used. Use the following command to solve this problem.*

```
ngrok http -host-header=localhost:5000
```

---

Try to set `keep_alive = False`.

```
s = requests.session()
s.keep_alive = False
```

Try to add `Connection=close` in headers.

```
headers = {
            'Connection': 'close',
            'Content-type': 'application/json', 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply, but unfortunately the error message remains.

Comment: @ChsharpNewbie Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: have tried, unfortunately also does not work

Comment: @ChsharpNewbie Can you tell me, your webapi and python code in same pc ?

Comment: @ChsharpNewbie I think it was the firewall block port 5000. You need to allow it.

Comment: My ASP Net Core application is also running on the same computer as the Python client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236930/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-chsharpnewbie).